# Универсальный язык для математических операций

Tags: javascript, java, objective-c, swift

Я разрабатываю приложение которое работает на  Android , iOS и веб.
Существенная часть приложения это математические операции над массивами, различные фильтры и т.д.
Мне приходиться писать один и тот же код на java, obj-c и на javascript.
Есть ли возможность написать код на каком-то универсальном языке, который я потом смогу перенести легко на java, obj-c и на javascript.

Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Существует MatLab, это то что вам нужно и там почти все готово.
Единственное правильно его подключите.

А вот собственно и [документация](http://matlab.ru/products/matlab-compiler/matlab-compiler_rus_web.pdf).

От javascript, лучше отказаться и использовать ajax запросы к серверу, мало ли с какого полена зайдет пользователь.

Comment: Спасибо. Я думал про это... на практике алгоритмы мы как раз и пишем изначально на матлабе.. тока сервек node.js и от javascript как тут отказаться

Comment: @phnmnn, Простите, с node.js не работал. Но на вашем месте я бы написал службу которая будет вертеться на сервере и работать по заданным входным данным. А уже после обращался бы к данной службе.

Answer (score 0):

Можно посмотреть в сторону `C`. Objective-C просто может использовать код написанный на C, также C можно конвертировать в Java и Javascript.